# Word to denote "recent" in a relative timeframe

Tags: single-word-requests, time

I'm looking for a word to replace *[recent](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recent)* when the reference point is not the present.

For example, I want to describe the time/events of the period shortly before the rule of Alfred the Great (what Alfred himself would refer to as "recent history"). A writer at the time could write something like "King Alfred continued a trend set by recent kings and events to establish himself as the dominant ruler in England". If I were to write that today, I would be technically incorrect (although probably understood in this example). What can I replace *recent* with to make this correct?

The sample sentence I'm looking to put the desired word into is thus

> King Alfred continued a trend set by ______ kings and events to establish himself as the dominant ruler in England.

Note that the length of the time periods we're talking about (how short, exactly, is "shortly before") is vague and depends on context, which is absolutely fine, and is not the point of my question.

To clarify further, here's an analogy: the word *[contemporary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/contemporary)* can be used to mean "of the present time" (technically, "of the same time", with the present being the explicit or implicit reference point), but it can also be used with different reference points (e.g., "Salieri was contemporary with Mozart"). On the other hand, *[modern](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/modern)* always refers to the present time (this is why I find words like *modernism* and *postmodernism* to be nonsense, but I digress).

To phrase the analogy as an SAT question, I'm looking for a word that is to *recent* what *contemporary* is to *modern*.

*Earlier* comes to mind as a possibility which works with any reference point, but *earlier* is more generic: it can include periods much further in the past, disconnected from the reference point, while *recent* describes a period (of indefinite length) leading up to the present.

**EDIT**

I realised the original example sounds a bit awkward, so I thought having another, simpler sentence might help:

> In 1940, my grandmother was meant to travel to Australia with her parents, but she didn't because she had ______ given birth.

Comment: In other words, you want a word that means "slightly earlier"?

Comment: What are you asking? Strangely, you *already* gave "contemporary," one sense of which is being "recent in a relative time frame." Only *one* sense of "contemporary" means "modern." Ironically, this means that "*contemporary* [2] is to *recent* as *contemporary* [3] is to *modern*.

Comment: @aparente001, yes, if you also take "slightly" to be an indefinite amount dependent on context (same as "shortly before" that I've mentioned).

Comment: @JasonBassford, I think there's a fine difference between "modern" and "recent" that should be reflected in the relationship between "contemporary" and our target word: "modern" refers to an indefinite period of time around the present while "recent" refers to an indefinite period of time up to the present (so it's purely in the past).

Comment: @Ratler What? No, I mean that *contemporary* has *multiple* senses. One of its senses is "around the same time period." In other words, "Plato was a contemporary of Socrates." That sense doesn't mean *modern* at all. Or to rephrase the sentence in the question, "King Alfred continued a trend set by kings and events *contemporary* to him to establish himself as the dominant ruler in England." Although, perhaps what you're looking for is something that means "slightly before relatively contemporary."

Comment: @JasonBassford, exactly, "slightly before contemporary" is the goal. I guess I was saying that there's a nuance that makes _contemporary_ unsuitable for the example sentence (e.g., the battle of Ellandun was not contemporary to Alfred, but was recent history to him; but let's not get caught up in history as this was a random example anyway!).

Comment: @Ratler Hmm. Five years ago would be "recent" to us, but I don't think you're going to find a word that means 5,005 years ago rather than 5,000 years ago when talking about something that happened relative to that 5,000-year-old event. But—could you provide a sample sentence in which such a word (or words) might be placed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79366/discussion-between-ratler-and-jason-bassford).

Comment: *King Alfred continued a trend set by **earlier** kings and events to establish himself as the dominant ruler in England.*  It's not perfect, and I hope someone with a sophisticated vocabulary comes up with a word to match your description.  But I think this works well enough.

Comment: Please submit answers as answers rather than in comments. It's difficult to engage with them in an already unwieldy comment thread.

Comment: The word you want is [antecedent](https://books.google.com/books?id=HNckDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT75&ots=D11htAhINI&dq=%22antecedent%20kings%22&pg=PT75#v=onepage&q=%22antecedent%20kings%22&f=false). But the sentence needs some help. *Trends* is not the right word here. You want something like *actions*. And *events*, what ever they were, isn't parallel with *kings* and doesn't fit.

Comment: @PhilSweet, true, the sentence is a bit awkward, but it's just a made-up example to explain what I'm looking for. I should've probably used something simpler.

Comment: Do you reeeeealy need a single word? Because "his immediate predecessors" would be unambiguous.

Comment: @Spencer, no, I was just wondering if such a word exists. I agree that small phrases, such as "imediate predecessors" or "shortly before that", would do the job in most examples.

Comment: _Immediately previous_ is possible.

Comment: 'In 1940, my grandmother was meant to travel to Australia with her parents, but she didn't because she had **recently** given birth. works fine. 'Recent' is deictic, 'shortly before the referenced time'. // Admittedly, 'King Alfred continued a trend set by recent kings and events to establish himself as the dominant ruler in England.' is not quite as natural sounding, but is still totally acceptable on grounds of grammaticality, semantics and clarity.

Answer (score -1):

'precedented kings'
'former' kings
'previous' kings
in my opinion it doesn't really matter that it should be quite close to the timeframe of Alfred, as if you indicate that it was the kings before him it includes that timeframe as well.

Comment: _Precedented_ doesn't seem appropriate from the dictionary definition ("example set for future use"). _Former_ and _previous_ could work, but as with _earlier_, they don't convey that the timeframe is necessarily connected to the point of reference (i.e., it could've been a long time ago).

Comment: aren't the previous kings examples set for future use in that context? Yes, I realize that. That is why I said in my opinion it doesn't really matter whether it's a long time ago. (does it really? It surely includes the recent past kings as well as the long ago kings as well...)

Answer (score -2):

**latter-day**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/latter-day)

> Belonging to present or *recent* times

As in:

> King Alfred continued a trend set by **latter day** kings and events
>   to establish himself as the dominant ruler in England.

2 other dictionaries:

*modern or contemporary, especially mirroring the past*. Oxford

*being a new or recent form of a person or thing from the past*. Cambridge

Comment: From the link you posted, "latter-day" means "of a later or following period". I guess that can be taken to mean "modern or recent times" since on the timeline of history, the present comes later / at the end, but in the example, I'm afraid it could be understood as "the kings/events that came **after** Alfred".

Comment: @Ratler au contraire! By definition it in no way can mean a post date, or relate to the 'future'.

Comment: One of the TFD examples is "of a later or following period: latter-day pioneers". I read that as "pioneers that came after the main or original pioneers" (i.e., in the future of the **reference  point**). Do you mean that this should be read as "slightly earlier pioneers"?

Comment: @Ratler  the ladder day pioneers came after the 1st pioneers but before the current pioneer.

Comment: But which version is understood by people? If, let's say, somebody said "compare the fourth Holy Land crusade (1202) with latter-day crusades", would people understand it to mean pre-1202 or last crusades (late 1200s)? I would assume the second interpretation.

Answer (score -2):

I would say: "King Alfred's leadership style was comparable to kings of that era."

Note: Rulership style is an actual concept. Khublai Khan is one of my ancestors. His rulership style was purely administrative. He let his people keep their customs. This is known as _______.

Comment: The question asks for a *single word* rather than a different way to say the whole sentence. For future reference, we are also looking for answers with correct punctuation – I've [edit]ed your post to fix the errors, but note that lack of care on a site catering to English language/usage enthusiasts is an invitation for downvotes! Lastly, what is the purpose of your second paragraph? Are you asking us to fill in the blank?